# Are fluorocarbons in chain lubricants a real environmental issue?

Tags: chain, lubricant

Some chain lubricants contain fluorocarbons like PTFE or other substances
called PFAS. Is this a genuine environmental issue? Should I avoid all
lubricants containing fluorocarbons?

I have heard that in ski waxes, fluorocarbons are starting to become
forbidden. Should the same fluorocarbon ban apply to bicycle chain lubricants
too?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about PTFE.  Yes, it lasts forever, but that's because [nothing reacts with it](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34190/5396).

Comment: @Mark Research is ongoing regarding the health and safety aspects of PTFE use. Its chemical inertness doesn’t excuse it from potentially being dangerous. At the very least, it can serve as a micro plastic which never breaks down, running the risk of mechanically clogging blood vessels and whatnot if introduced into the body.

Comment: @Mark From the link I gave in my answer: _In 2018, the European Food Safety Authority (EFSA) re-evaluated the multiple lines of evidence of PFOA and PFOS toxicities, which resulted in significantly lower provisional ‘safe’ limits, known as the ‘tolerable weekly intake’ (TWI) (EFSA, 2018). The assessment concluded that a considerable proportion of the European population is expected to exceed the TWI due to intake of PFAS from food and drinking water._ There's also an infographics from the US National Toxicology Program with the potential effect in some diseases/cancers.

Comment: @Renaud, PFOA and PFOS both have functional groups tacked on to the carbon chain, which makes them far more reactive than PTFE, which is just straight carbon and fluorine.

Answer (score 10):

The European Environment Agency has declared that PFAS are an [emerging chemical risk](https://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/emerging-chemical-risks-in-europe/emerging-chemical-risks-in-europe). As indicated in this page, the effects of this components is not yet entirely understood, but there negative known effects, and this kind of pollutant does not degrade over time.

There are alternatives, maybe not as good/convenient. If you hesitate and care about the environmental impact, I would answer by this question by the precautionary principle, not by computing the mass that is produced to cover the needs of "cycling".

Note that cycling may be a minor contributor in relative terms, but may have an bigger impact than other sectors, such as cookware, because cycling happens outdoor, and the chemicals released go straight in the environment. This kind of factor is not taken into consideration if you only look at the mass.

Comment: What are the environment friendly alternatives? Do they turn black after usage?

Comment: The alternatives are PFAS-free lubricants. Turning black after usage is linked to ambiant contamination, the only way to avoid it I'm aware of is to use wax instead of liquid lubes.

Comment: I've checked what is available. Finish Line chain wax has molybdenum. I think it is better than PFAS.

Comment: Molybdenum is a nutrient for plants, so definitely better (if not in excess, as usual, but unlikely that it would be case with residues from bike chains).

Comment: @Ender Molybdenum is also one of the replacement ingredients for PFAS in ski waxes. It should be better.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we need to know how much fluorocarbons are released to the
environment. In European Union, [75 kilotonnes](https://www.kemi.se/archives/news-archive/news/2023-02-08-new-eu-restriction-can-stop-all-manufacture-and-sale-of-pfas) of PFAS end up in environment. So, to estimate if bicycling
is a major contributor to this, we need to calculate the percentage of
PFAS that would be emitted by bicyclists should every bicyclist use PFAS
lubricants.

As examples of fluorocarbon-containing chain lubricants, the Rex Black Diamond
and Domestique chain lubricants apparently contain fluorocarbons. They are sold
in 30 gram bottles, good for 30 applications. From this we know that 1 gram per
application is used.

We also need to estimate how much fluorocarbons are contained in a gram of this
lubricant. I was unable to find any information. However, I was able to find
that [Mspeedwax contains 5 grams of PTFE per 500 grams of wax](https://zerofrictioncycling.com.au/latest-zero-friction-cycling-news-ptfe/), or 1 percent. However, it's
likely that Mspeedwax is a very low-PTFE wax, since they confirm this small
amount is going to be phased out. By pouring Rex Black Diamond into a
disposable shot glass, I definitely see it's mostly liquid oil and not solid
fluorocarbons, so I'd estimate this lubricant probably contains 5 percent
solids (fluorocarbons).

I was able to find information that the average Finnish person rides bike 234
km/year. (I was unable to find EU-wide statistics for this.)
European union has a population of 447.7 million, so about 104.8
billion kilometers/year are ridden in EU.

Rex says that a single application of its lubricants lasts 500 km. However, [Zero Friction Cycling](https://zerofrictioncycling.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Single-Longevity-sept22.pdf) got 5602 km in a lab and estimate that in real-world conditions you would get 1867 km. My experience also is that even a very cheap chain lubricant easily lasts 800 km, so let's say a single lubrication lasts 1000 km.

So, 104.8 million lubrications per year are needed in EU. Each lubrication of 1
gram contains probably 0.05 grams of fluorocarbons. Therefore, 0.00524
kilotonnes of fluorocarbons would be released to environment should every
cyclist use these fluorocarbon containing lubricants. That's 0.007% of the
total PFAS emissions. Very insignificant.

However, it should be remembered this applies to wet lubricants that last a
really long time and consist mostly of oil (with little bit of fluorocarbons
extra). A dry lubricant that contains lots of fluorocarbons as the sole
lubricant and some evaporating solvent needs to be applied far more often and
contains more fluorocarbons, so the results could be even two orders of
magnitude worse. Still, if every cyclist would use these horrible dry
lubricants, cycling would still create only 0.7% of the PFAS emissions.

About ski waxes: [15 grams will wax 1-2 pairs of adult skis](https://www.sidecut.com/product/WAX_NX_CFXII_15G.html). Let's say 2, so 7.5 grams per pair are used.
However, a lot of this could be wasted: [it has been measured that a single ski has only about 1.1 g of wax remaining](https://kmadventures.com/how-much-glide-wax-do-we-waste/). That's
2.2 g per pair. One waxing endures [40 kilometers](https://vauhti.fi/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Waxing-Guide-for-Liquid-Products_ENG_web.pdf), so this means 55 grams of wax are used per 1000 km. You can
contrast that to bicycling which uses 1 gram of chain oil per 1000 km.

So skiing leaves behind 55 times the amount of wax than cycling leaves the
amount of chain oil, per kilometer. Thus, it can't be said that the fluorocarbon ban in ski
waxes should be extended to cycling as so little chain oil is left behind.

Comment: What are considered the acceptable levels in the environment.  "I pollute less than he do, so I do not need to change" is poor justification for continuing to do something that is bad for the environment (and largely how the world got into the mess it is).

Comment: MSW's current formulation already eliminates PTFE. Also note that PTFE has environmental implications when it's being manufactured. These may outweigh the damage from releasing it into the environment.

Comment: My biggest gripe against wet lube is dust/mud contamination, as wet lube is a magnet for particles — I ride off-road, but not the technical style, which includes a lot of dolomite "roads". Do not forget that zero friction cycling results are lab results. In practice, I have to clean my chain much more when using wet lube than dry lube because of that.

Comment: @mattnz perhaps you could say the world got into the mess it is because of self-amplifying loops "Alice pollutes, so I might as well do too" - "Why should I stop polluting, Bob is doing it as well" - "Alice and Bob are both driving cars every day, so what does it matter even if I get that dirty SUV" - "Hey, Charlie got an SUV, I want one too"... Stopping this kind of tragedy is important, but OTOH denying old Daisy her Prius that she needs to get her shopping done every two weeks really would not make sense as it has quite negligible impact compared to the others.

Comment: This answer conveniently ignores that the amount of kilometers travelled by bike will be magnitudes higher than the amount of skiing kilometers logged.

Comment: @mattnz on the other hand "I pollute an order of magnitude less" means that eliminating my tiny bit of usage would be rounding error, and my finite efforts would better be spent elsewhere.

Comment: You can skip the complicated math. *All* of the chemicals that are in the bottle will eventually end up in the environment, and none of the PFAS will ever degrade. PFAS-free lubricant additives, such as tungsten disulfide, exist and perform just as well or better.