# What chain Maintenace (lube and cleaner) ingredients should I prefer (or avoid) with respect to environmental concerns

Tags: chain

This question > [Are fluorocarbons in chain lubricants a real environmental issue?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89176/are-fluorocarbons-in-chain-lubricants-a-real-environmental-issue) got me thinking about the broader issue of the environmental impact of our choice of chain lube and cleaner.

If I am prepared to sacrifice some performance, maybe clean a bit more often and add lube on a long ride in the interest of a small contribution to saving the planet, what ingredients should I be looking to avoid when selecting a chain lube.  What ingredients that are environmentally friendly work well (or not) as a chain lube.  How much more (or less) effort will my choice likely take?

Answer (score 2):

Look for the chain waxes with molybdenum but it is still a petroleum based product at the end of the day. I don't know how strong contaminator PFAS is. Maybe a tiny drop of it contaminates hundreds gallons of water. You can do much more for the planet if you stop consuming industrial fed cow meat.

Comment: Petroleum is hydrocarbons. Molybdenum and tungsten are transition metals - how are they petroleum based?

Comment: @WeiwenNg the parafin wax is, I think.

Comment: @WeiwenNg "Typically lubricants contain 90% base oil (most often petroleum fractions, called mineral oils) and less than 10% additives." 
I think Molybdenum is just an additive, not the base oil.